# entity framework not available in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I have a strange error with Visual Studio 2010 in that Entity Framework doesn't work for me.

In the toolbox down the side the icon for the EntityDataSource (and several other components) shows a text snippet icon:

[image: EntityDataSource as text snippet]

Then when I try to insert it via double clicking I just get a massive bunch of text inserted instead of the control:

[image: EntityDataSource inserts soap-env]

I have tried installing the latest Entity Framework 4.1 standalone installer. I have also installed the Visual Studio 2010 SP1. I did have the SP1 RC installed before but the install notes for SP1 state clearly that you don't need to uninstall the RC before installing the final SP1.

I have been using Linq to SQL for a long time now and finally wanted to start learning EF so I am not sure how long this has been broken and I just haven't noticed.

It seems that the issue has occurred for others:

- http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/622189/entitydatasource-control-is-missing-from-my-visual-studio-2010-ultimate-toolbox

But Microsoft closed the bug as not-reproducible. I commented on there about a month ago but nothing has been responded to.

As I stated in that thread I did try the fix suggested but it didn't work.

Does anybody have any idea what steps I can take to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the most obvious solution doesn't occur until after you have spent 10 minutes taking screenshots and posting up a question on SO.

I have just solved this issue by right clicking on the toolbox and choose Reset Toolbox.